# Build intersection type without object copy

Tags: typescript

I have a service call which gives me an object and I want to store more data in that object. I have abstracted it as much as possible:

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTCWDsAIBcAsFNICd4EMA2kDOqC2AHdeAGkgEkBGSVcAExgW3iQDdQBjeAYQ01RUgBzeOGapo8ejXplItAPaRw86JADuNVdEXtYNYQ3i4AUBAlIAZqk7kKAbyV54ALmzQkEQQG5IAX2MWAK7g7NCg8lBYzGycPOjoABQAlM6UkHYo0IFIUHbgTs4ARAAS8PGKAOrySOi0hb5e-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)

```js
//in the real sample, I1 and the serviceCall are generated and I do not want to change them
interface I1{ name: string; }
function serviceCall():I1 {return {name:"Hello World"};}

const o1:I1 = serviceCall();

interface I2 { age: number; }

// I want to store the data of I2 in the same object, so my target type is (I1&I2)
type target = (I1&I2);

//solution 1: this copies all of o1 into a new object. I want no extra copy!
const o2copy:target = {...o1, age: 144};

//solution 2: casting
const o2cast:target = o1 as target;
//works but does not check anything! 
//age is undefined until I set it but it does not give me any error if I leave the next line!
o2cast.age = 144;

//solution 3: simply setting the property: the javascript is fine, but typescript yields errors
o1.age = 144; //ERROR: property age does not exist on I1
const o2setprop:target = o1;
```

solution 3 would be my favorite, how can I make that compile?

Comment: You can't make that compile, you either cast and ensure that the code is safe manually if you have a really hot loop or something, or just copy because this is javascript and performance implications of a single shallow copy is probably irrelevant.

Comment: in real, I have an array of objects and each object has also more data. I reduced the problem as much as possible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy the properties from `{age: 144}` into your target `o1` object.  This function returns `o1`, and the return type of [the standard library's type signature for it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b944ce557c60d165ae31c106bf9fb63ad36afe54/src/lib/es2015.core.d.ts#L266) is an intersection type, as desired:

```
const o2: target = Object.assign(o1, { age: 144 });
console.log(o2.name.toUpperCase()); // HELLO WORLD
console.log(o2.age.toFixed(1)); // 144.0
```

Note that an intersection is just an approximation of the actual type that `Object.assign()` returns.  If you pass parameters with conflicting properties, an intersection wll be inaccurate.  In your example code, however, this is not an issue.

The compiler will still see `o1` as type `I1`, though, so you will have to start using `o2` exclusively and forget about `o1`:

```
o1.age; // compiler error!
// ~~~ <-- I1 has no property named "age"
```

---

If you really want to keep `o1` without having to use a new variable name for it, you might consider making use of [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) as introduced in TypeScript 3.7.  There is no built-in version of `Object.assign()` that acts as an assertion function, but you can write one:

```
function assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): asserts target is T & U {
    Object.assign(target, source);
}
```

The return type of `assign` is `asserts target is T & U`.  So after you call `assign(o1, {age: 144}`, the compiler will treat `o1` as being `I1 & {age: number}`:

```
assign(o1, { age: 144 });
console.log(o1.name.toUpperCase()); // HELLO WORLD
console.log(o1.age.toFixed(1)); // 144.0
```

This might be the way you want to go, but keep in mind that assertion function implementations are not verified as type safe by the compiler.  It is the responsibility of the author of such a function to ensure that after the function is called, the type narrowing asserted in its return type actually happens.  Nothing would warn you if, for example, you didn't do anything inside the function:

```
function badAssign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): asserts target is T & U { }
```

In such cases you are lying to the compiler inside `badAssign()`, and anyone who uses it will be in trouble:

```
badAssign(o1, { oops: "uh oh" });
o1.oops.toUpperCase(); // no compiler error, but runtime error!
```

So take care with this approach.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEZkG9kjgWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5kBfAKBgFcQExgB7EM6AN2BIAwnAA2YgBQBKEhmzIoEMCyi8ceQiQBEACQgSuyAOpcoYgCbaGdJgh7lkXdHMwBePlEEjxU6TUZGUEhYRBRUACYFOCpiXBZ8ACNoW0YwAE8ABxQwOChYsGQPSXkAMjQI-0D7EEcuCJJc-OUi5AB5RIArCA4AOjhSUmAqEElnABpo2JJ0ABZZhiqa0i4xCF6xLioxiN7NdbAuAFVM7KhRUggZf2QAelvkXQBRABkXtpM2gCUXgBFGZardabbb1fqxXqHABiwAAHhALJJ0NIbvdkHNZr0AAyBZzgiB0NH2fCZYBrKDIaBQMwAQkYaIAfkzkAAeAC0bLQmAAFgNcEZMtSzhlcAQEchtDEINpAqx2JweMgBkMRiyACqTI4APkkTQKJA1ZC4qiQJCOsiVg2gYFIyD1LWAtrVyHKR2wjGQnvaXR6YH6g2Go3tYEmKxNECqTECysDY3QkxwUpm80WAUBaw2WzjezFkOOp2gFyuKMJD2ebw+xm+fwBDiBmdB6HxeZh8MRyNRDwx2MCzDYHG4vEScAsAEEA6rDdrdXl9chDWGoKbkOaSMrrbbg8hHfOXSuFExh2OJ6MJgouFxMqQdCxuU5udZ6FU8Rer3mTmcizJS-zkMTSeSlJQNSUCTIkLCFFAbCcIQQEgTSQA)

Comment: I knew about assertion functions, but it never came to my mind, that they can change the "asserted" object! With proper naming, every team mate should understand what it does. thanks for your thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this:

```
const o2setprop:target = setProp(o1, "age", 144);


function setProp<T, P, K extends keyof any>(obj: T, k: K, val: P): T & { [_ in K]: P } {
    const o = obj as any
    o[k] = val
    return o
}
```

Comment: I like @jcalz approach a litte more as it is easier to add more than one property in one go. I guess over simplified my question in that regard. Thanks for your answer. Please tell me, you had to look up that type description, that is really bunch of description :-)

Comment: @fabsenet It's a pretty simple type definition if you know how to use mapped types. Mapped, conditional ,and recursive types are definitely the best typescript feature no one knows how to use, imho everyone should learn!